# Import cycle in tensorflow protobufs

Tags: tensorflow, go, protocol-buffers, tensorflow-serving, buf

I am trying to write client code to talk to a tensorflow server. I need the golang compiled protobufs for `tensorflow` and `tensorflow_serving`. These are not easy to come by, I managed to do so through [this](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/how-do-you-compile-the-tf-serving-proto-files/11042). Basically, using [buf](https://buf.build/docs/) to generate them. Here is the buf yaml:

```yaml
version: v1
managed:
  enabled: true
  optimize_for: CODE_SIZE

  # Go
  go_package_prefix:
    default: "some/path"

plugins:
  - plugin: buf.build/protocolbuffers/go
    out: gen/proto/go
```

This runs successfully, but running the application logs:

```bash
 package command-line-arguments
     imports my-package/internal/infer
     imports my-package/internal/infer/tensorflow_serving/apis
     imports my-package/internal/infer/tensorflow/core/protobuf
     imports my-package/internal/infer/tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor
     imports my-package/internal/infer/tensorflow/compiler/xla
     imports my-package/internal/infer/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service
     imports my-package/internal/infer/tensorflow/compiler/xla: import cycle not allowed
```

Note that everything under `tensorflow` and `tensorflow_serving` is directly compiled from the original repositories.

It is surprising to me that something as widely used as tensorflow should have an import cycle, but maybe it does. How can I resolve this?

Comment: @ZekeLu everything under `tensorflow` and `tensorflow_serving` is directly compiled from the repositories.

Comment: Are you in a virtual environment? Just to be sure. This import cycle is probably the result of your direct compilation of both tensorflow and tensorflow_serving (in same dir?). One approach is you install them separately and somehow symlink them. Or, try your approach just for tensorflow_serving or tensorflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

The root cause is that the repositry https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow does not organize the proto files correctly (or at least does not make it friendly for Go).

The following two files lead to the import cycle (`xla`->`xla/service`->`xla`) in Go:

- `tensorflow/compiler/xla/xla.proto`

  - `import "tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/hlo.proto"`
- `tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/hlo.proto`

  - `import "tensorflow/compiler/xla/xla_data.proto"`

Since `xla_data.proto` does not import any other files, we can move it into its own package to break the import cycle. We can utilize the [override feature of buf](https://buf.build/docs/configuration/v1/buf-gen-yaml/#override-1) to do this. Here is the final `buf.gen.yaml` file:

```yaml
version: v1
managed:
  enabled: true
  go_package_prefix:
    default: example.com/mymodule/internal
  override:
    GO_PACKAGE:
      # move the generated xla_data.pb.go file into package xla/data to break the import cycle.
      tensorflow/compiler/xla/xla_data.proto: 'example.com/mymodule/internal/tensorflow/compiler/xla/data'
plugins:
  - name: go
    out: internal
    opt:
      - module=example.com/mymodule/internal

  - name: go-grpc
    out: internal
    opt:
      - module=example.com/mymodule/internal
```

---

#### The Full Setup to Compile Tensorflow proto Files with buf

Here is the final directory structure:

```
├── buf.gen.yaml
├── buf.work.yaml
├── buf.yaml
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── internal
│   ├── tensorflow
│   └── tensorflow_serving
└── testdata
    ├── serving
    └── tensorflow
```

**buf.gen.yaml**: see the "TL;DR" section.

**buf.work.yaml**:

```yaml
version: v1
directories:
  - testdata/serving
  - testdata/tensorflow
```

**buf.yaml**:

```yaml
version: v1
breaking:
  use:
    - FILE
lint:
  use:
    - DEFAULT
```

Here is my environment:

```
$ go version
go version go1.20.3 linux/amd64
$ buf --version
1.17.0
$ protoc --version
libprotoc 3.12.4
$ protoc-gen-go --version
protoc-gen-go v1.30.0
$ protoc-gen-go-grpc --version
protoc-gen-go-grpc 1.3.0
$ git version
git version 2.37.2
```

Now execute the following commands in the root of this directory:

```
$ go mod init example.com/mymodule
$ go get google.golang.org/grpc
$ git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git testdata/tensorflow
$ git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/serving.git testdata/serving
$ buf generate
$ go build ./...
```

**Notes**:

1. The tensorflow repositories are cloned into the `testdata` directory so that `go build` will ignore them.
2. The setup generates the files into the `internal` directory. You can modify the `buf.gen.yaml` file to place them anywhere you want.
3. `go build ./...` does not report any error. But I'm not sure whether the generated files are valid or not.