# I want to generate protobufs from proto files from cmd without using "option go_package "

Tags: go, grpc, protobuf-go

I have to generate protobuf file from a proto file which import another proto file.
One another requirement, this has to be generated by cmd (by not defining "option go_package" in the proto file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have 3 files **foo.proto**, **poo.proto** and **zoo.proto**. The file **foo.proto** imports a message struct from **poo.proto** and **zoo.proto**. You need to write the command in a specific order which puts **foo.proto(importing from other)** first and **poo.proto(giving import to other)** and **zoo.proto(giving import to other)** after that.

Here is the command to generate protobufs without defining **option go_package**

```
protoc --proto_path=./ --go_out=./pb --go-grpc_out=./pb
--go_opt=Mfoo.proto=./ --go-grpc_opt=Mfoo.proto=./
--go_opt=Mpoo.proto=./ --go-grpc_opt=Mpoo.proto=./
--go_opt=Mzoo.proto=./ --go-grpc_opt=Mzoo.proto=./
foo.proto goo.proto zoo.proto
```

Notice the **M** before filename, it replaces **option go_package** in your code

**foo.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "goo.proto";
import "zoo.proto";

service Foo {
    rpc FooRPC(PooMessage) returns (ZooMessage) {}
}
```

**poo.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

message PooMessage {
    string body = 1;
}
```

**zoo.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

message ZooMessage {
    string body = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `M` flag](https://protobuf.dev/reference/go/go-generated/#package) to specify the go package. This is an example for how to execute the `protoc` command:

```
protoc -I=protos \
       --go_out=. \
       --go_opt=Mperson.proto=internal/pb \
       --go_opt=Maddressbook.proto=internal/pb \
       person.proto addressbook.proto
```

The directory structure for the above command is:

```
└── protos
    ├── addressbook.proto
    └── person.proto
```

**protos/person.proto**:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package example;

message Person {
  string name = 1;
  int32 id = 2;
  string email = 3;
}
```

**protos/addressbook.proto**:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package example;

import "person.proto";

message AddressBook {
  repeated Person people = 1;
}
```

And the final directory structure is:

```
├── internal
│   └── pb
│       ├── addressbook.pb.go
│       └── person.pb.go
└── protos
    ├── addressbook.proto
    └── person.proto
```

For complex use cases, it's recommended to use [Buf](https://buf.build/docs/). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76090608/1369400) shows how it can be used to generate code from complex proto files.